# Is it possible to set a maximum velocity on a object?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a object set to rigid body. I am using *Linear Velocity* set to *Add* to make it jump. Is it possible to set a maximum velocity so it will not keep speeding up infinitely?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the maximum (and mimimum) velocity of a rigid body object in the Properties Editor.
[image]